# How to improve regex while fetching record dynamically

Tags: python, regex

The data is as follows:

```
COL1    COL2

 12    :402:agsh,hhjd,:45:hghgh,gruru,:12:fgh,ghgh,:22:hhhh
 57    :42:agshhhjd,:57:hghgh,gruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:hhhhhh
```

I am creating a third column `field_info` like:

```
 COL1  COL2                                                    field_info

 12   :402:agsh,hhjd,:45:hghghgruru,:12:fgh,ghgh,:22:hhhh      fgh,ghg
 57   :42:agshhhjd :57:hghgh,gruru:120:fghghgh :12:hhhhhh    hghgh,g
```

I am using a regex function as follows:

```
df.loc[:,'field_info']=df.col2.replace(regex=r'.*'+ df.col1.astype('str') +':(.{15}).*',value="\\1")
```

I have 2 columns col1 & col2. col1 has some value which I am searching in col2 dynamically and extracting the next 15 characters from that. However, it's taking a lot of time. Can anyone suggest a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Would you have a python notebook or google collab so we can play with your code ?

Comment: notebook or .python file

Comment: As you prefer as long as it makes it possible to reproduce your code

Comment: Actually my code is stuck at this part for over 45 mins while i am working with just 150000 records. Any faster way of improving the regex such that it takes less time?

Comment: You should try it with less records (10 - 100) for example. The points I would check are:
- does it make sense to have a dataframe column in the regex.
- could you precompile your regex

Comment: i could work it with upto 85000 records. With the increase of the data volume to 2 times, i have been noticing the problem.

Comment: well I have some amount of data in col2 which includes numbers special chacaracters,etc and some value in col2. On finding the value in col2 present in col1, i need to extract 15 characters from there. I did not find any other solution apart from using regex. Could u help?

Comment: Sorry but without reproducible code I cannot help you

Comment: what do you mean by reproducible code? could u explain?

Comment: Some code I could run on my computer to reproduce your error even with a small part of your dataframe

Comment: I think you should try string slicing. First, find the starting index of col1 in col2 (lets say index1), then add the length of col1 to that index (which will become index2), then with this new index just get the 15 characters you want using `col2[index2:index2+15]`.

Comment: UPdated the question @RobinNicole@Ankit Seth

Answer (score 1):

```
string = ':402:agsh,hhjd,:45:hghghgruru,:12:fgh,ghgh,:22:hhhh'
place = string.find('12')
def extract_substring(string, num):
    starting_point = place + len('12')
    return string[starting_point:(starting_point + 15)]
df.apply(lambda row:extract_substring(row['col2'], row['col1']), axis=1)
%timeit df.loc[:,'field_data']=df.col2.replace(regex=r'.*'+ df.col1.astype('str') +':(.{15}).*',value="\\1")
```

Should work as well, and doesn't use regexp

Answer (score 0):

Based on your sample data, I replicated it 50000 times and the result is as follows-

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'COL1':[12 ,57],'COL2': [':402:agsh,hhjd,:45:hghgh,gruru,:12:fgh,ghgh,:22:hhhh',':42:agshhhjd,:57:hghgh,gruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:hhhhhh']})

>>> for _ in range(50000):
        df = df.append({'COL1':12,'COL2': ':402:agsh,hhjd,:45:hghgh,gruru,:12:fgh,ghgh,:22:hhhh'}, ignore_index = True)
        df = df.append({'COL1':57,'COL2': ':42:agshhhjd,:57:hghgh,gruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:hhhhhh'}, ignore_index = True)

>>> df.shape 
(100002, 2)
```

Then I defined a custom function and applied to the columns-

```py
>>> def somefunc(x,y):
        res = []
        for i in range(len(x)):
            ix = y[i].find(x[i]) + len(x[i])
            res.append(y[i][ix+1:ix+8])
        return res

>>> df['col3'] = somefunc(df['COL1'].astype(str),df['COL2'])
>>> df.head()
    COL1                                   COL2             col3 
0    12  :402:agsh,hhjd,:45:hghgh,gruru,:12:fgh,ghgh,:2...  fgh,ghg
1    57  :42:agshhhjd,:57:hghgh,gruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:...  hghgh,g
2    12  :402:agsh,hhjd,:45:hghgh,gruru,:12:fgh,ghgh,:2...  fgh,ghg
3    57  :42:agshhhjd,:57:hghgh,gruru,:120:fghghgh,:12:...  hghgh,g
```

I did not use regex and this function took nearly 5 seconds to complete on 100000 rows.

Comment: Its giving me key error for the APPEND line

Comment: Can you post the full error and the particular data in which you are getting error?

Comment: line 47, in somefunc
           ix = y[i].find(x[i]) + len(x[i])
            line 767, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  base.py", line 3118, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 114, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 964, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
KeyError: 14